# Its correct grouping by month an Index?

Tags: statistics, grouping, google-trends

I am working with an index, from Google Trends, that is given four days per month. So I have four indexes per month. I want to know if it's correct to group all those data indexes by month. Or, since it's an index, it makes no sense to group them to analyze the summary results per month. Thank you.

I group the indexes by month.